# Can Appium run multiple different tests concurrently across multiple devices?

Tags: selenium, appium, selenium-grid, appium-android, appium-ios

I am new to Appium/Selenium parallel testing and I was wondering if one could run different tests concurrently across multiple devices? My team needs to reduce the total runtime of our UI tests and are not concerned with different OS versions affecting the behaviour of the application for these specific tests. I have been reading through many posts and trying to search for answers but all I can seem to find on the internet are articles, tutorials and forums on how to run the same test in parallel on multiple devices.

Can I run different tests concurrently on multiple devices without kicking off different tests manually, or is that a limitation of Appium? Ideally this would be implemented using an open source solution.

(Right now we are trying to use a JUnit approach for testing due to specific limitations of other tools. All tests are being written in Java.)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on your setup, you can accomplish this. However, a lot of your build automation and device management will need to be set up by you or your team custom, so you will not be able to use an out-of-the-box solution to do this.

I've accomplished the same with both Selenium and Appium -- you will need a test framework that allows for test execution with parameters, and your devices will need to be connected to separate USB hubs that each have their own virtual server attached.

Using NUnit, here's my approach:

- Generate .txt files for each different set of tests I want to run -- `test_list_1.txt, test_list_2.txt`, etc. Each list contains a different group of test cases to run.
- Write a build script to clean & build your project from scratch -- for C#, I use Cake.
- Set up a job in Jenkins that executes your build script and calls NUnit's console runner, which takes a `test_list` as a parameter. This initiates a test execution against a list of test cases

You should be able to build your Jenkins job against any test list you want, so you now have the ability to run your automation against different tests, as mentioned in your problem description.

Connect your virtual machines (which connect to your Appium devices) to Jenkins and add them as executors on your job. Now you have multiple machines to run your job against.

With this set up, you can run as many jobs as you have machines -- 4 VM's means 4 jobs, which means you can run 4 different sets of test cases concurrently.

Setting this up on my end was completely custom -- I used certain tools to accomplish individual steps, but it worked for our needs and we did accomplish concurrent execution against different sets of test cases.

Comment: Thanks. So for example if I wanted to run this on my local machine, would I be able to use a local Jenkins instance to do so? Using a local Jenkins instance, would I be able to start up multiple Appium servers on their own ports and then use something like NUnit's console runner to kick off a new list of tests which use a dedicated Appium server and mobile device? To clarify, 1 local Jenkins instance starts 4 Appium servers locally and then using the console runner I pass in the "test_list" which runs one of the test lists against one of the 4 devices? (Please let me know if that isn't clear.)

Comment: I guess what I want to know from this is do I need separate VMs to run the tests specified in the "test_list" files or would starting up multiple processes on the same machine do the trick?

Comment: So, the answer to this bit is actually no. You will need separate virtual machines for each NUnit console runner instance. I've personally tried using multiple NUnit instances on a single machine and it did not work concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your tests locally on multiple devices by creating multiple instances of appium server. Every Appium server should be running on different ip and proxy address. So you should set your capabilities for each instance accordingly. 
But there is another solution as well but that's bit costly. That is **AWS Device Farm**. AWS provides multiple real devices hosted at there servers which you can use for executions of your customised test suits. They give initially 1000 free test minutes. You have to create a maven project for your test scripts. I prefer using testng rather than Junit.

Comment: So why do you prefer TestNG over JUnit? Is it a functional preference or is it a personal preference?

Comment: It's a functional preference since reports provided by testng are way more detailed. And also testng is a new model based on Junit so definitely there are more advantages using that. And most importantly most cloud servers are now supporting testng.

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking , basically it's not possible.

You can't run different test cases on different devices.

Though you can run same test cases on wide range of devices using Hive or Browserstack or AWS device farm.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That does help, thanks! So I assume the same would then be true for Selenium web UI testing as well then? (Parallel testing is limited to the same test on multiple devices rather than different tests.)

Comment: I disagree that this is not possible -- with a custom setup, you can absolutely accomplish this. I have personally implemented it in the past.

Comment: you can have a look here : `https://discuss.appium.io/t/parallel-execution-on-two-devices-of-two-different-test-cases/21243`

Comment: @J.Adhikari In the link you have provided, is parallel/concurrent testing being achieved or is that more along the lines of specifying the run order of the tests? One of the commenters had specified that they wanted to achieve a peer-to-peer test where they had 2 tests interacting with each other and validating that the interactions were correct. I may not be understanding correctly but is that achieving the same goal as I have?